# Android: Cant refresh a listfragment from another activity

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I have a problem with my ListFragment. I cant access its ListAdapter because I always get NullPointerException when i try to do:

```
ListFragment fragment = (ListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fraglist1");
BaseAdapter adapter = (BaseAdapter) fragment.getListAdapter();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Below is my XML file where I implement the fragment:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.example.exapmle.handlers.fragments.SavedEventsListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is what I have in my SavedEventsListFragment.java class,there is an onItemClick method right after the code snippet but that has nothing to do with it, so i cut it.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fraglist, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    savedevents = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getContext());
    for (Event e : db.getAllEvents()) {
        savedevents.add(e);
    }


    if (savedevents!=null) {
        SavedEventAdapter adapter = new SavedEventAdapter(getContext(), savedevents);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

        ListView lv = getListView(); // your listview inside scrollview
        lv.setOnTouchListener(new ListView.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        break;
                }

                // Handle ListView touch events.
                v.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here goes the SavedEventAdapter.java class, where I set the layout for the rows in ListView:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //ViewHolder holder;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fraglist_item, parent, false);

    Event e = getItem(position);

    TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);

    Date parsedstartdate = new Date();
    Date parseenddate = new Date();
    parsedstartdate.setTime(Long.parseLong(e.getStartdate())*1000);
    parseenddate.setTime(Long.parseLong(e.getEnddate())*1000);
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();

    title.setText(e.getTitle() + "\n" + df.format(parsedstartdate) + " - " + df.format(parseenddate));

    CheckBox chb = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.savedtodbchb);
    chb.setClickable(false);

    ImageView picture = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
    Picasso.with(context).load(e.getPicurl()).error(R.drawable.blackwallpaperbackground_big).resize(400,500).into(picture);
    picture.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(80,80,80), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    picture.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);


    return rowView;
```

Basically im trying to add the event to database, and when its added it should update the list in the activity where events in database are shown. I get this exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.vladmarton.eventaarhus, PID: 14022
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.ListAdapter android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.getListAdapter()' on a null object reference
at com.vladmarton.eventaarhus.EventDetailsActivity$1.onClick(EventDetailsActivity.java:122)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Maybe I miss something small, I already tried 2 other ways to do it that i found here on stackoverflow, but none of them helped. I have very small experience with ListFragments and its driving me crazy, so if someone has any idea, please comment :) Thanks

Comment: Post the stack trace as well.

Comment: Sorry, its updated now

Comment: Are you using same fragment instance using which you have performed beginTransaction?

Comment: Im not using transactions. And i dont know if i will answer your question sufficiently, but i use one instance of fragment.xml layout that i inflate twice in the app, the rest is coupled as i have two listfragments in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set a tag to the fragment, causing `findFragmentById()` to return null. Change your fragment in XML to this to add the tag.

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.example.exapmle.handlers.fragments.SavedEventsListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:tag="fraglist1" />
```

Comment: It didnt help... I already tried to use findFragmentById(R.id.fraglist1), its basically the same, and that didnt help as well

Comment: You would want `findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1)`.

Comment: Another thing to check, is your `SavedEventsListFragment` extending from the supportv4 version of `ListFragment`?

Comment: Yes sorry, i misspelled, R.id.fragment1. The class extends 'ListFragment'; i cant find any statement about supportv4, so I gues it isnt.

Comment: If you're not using the support library for your fragments/list fragment, then you should not be using `getSupportFragmentManager()`, you should be using `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Okay I just changed it to getFragmentManager and it shows me incompatible types, so it is v4 fragment indeed. I must confuse you a lot, sorry about that

Comment: If there's no `import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment` in your fragment, but you're looking for a supportv4 ListFragment in your activity, that mismatch will cause the problem as well.

Comment: Okay, thats weird, i just noticed that in my activity where I need to call notifyDataSetChanged() the v4 fragment is imported. I deleted the import, imported classic ListFragment and re-wrote the get manager to getFragmentManager(). I will try and let you know as soon as i get some results. Thanks for the help for now :)

Comment: Nope, it didnt help, i immidiately got the same NullPointerException. :/

Comment: And this is with the `android:tag` or correct id used for `findFragmentById/Tag()`? Hard to tell otherwise. Your Activity is unable to find the fragment, which is clear, but it's hard to otherwise tell what's the issue without more code.

Comment: Its the same with both. Well, from what I know, stackoverflow doesnt allow users to post the whole project and ask someone to take a look at it, and im also pretty sure that it would take a huge chunk of your time to get familiar with the code, so I really dont know what to do.

Comment: My next step recommendation would be to try adding the fragment programmatically (read more [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)) and give that a shot. I'm personally not a fan of having the fragments inflated from XML.

Comment: Sounds interesting, will give that a go, thanks for the tip ;) I will get back to you if I get it working somehow